# How to delete a record that stored in nested array foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach

Recently I've been self-learning PHP and doing a project for improving my skills.

I was trying to delete my items which I stored them in session array. First loop is based on renter after that only loop the items from array into cart that belong to that particular renter which this part is working well.

```
foreach($items as $rentid => $details){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM renter WHERE renter_id = $rentid";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Renter:<?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                </tr>
        <?php
            foreach($details as $d){
                $item_id = $d['item_id'];
                $qty = $d['qty'];
                $start_date = $d['start_date'];
                $end_date = $d['end_date'];
```

I was using this code to store the value from form

```
$items[$renter_id][] = [
    'item_id' => $itemid 
  , 'qty' => $qty
  , 'start_date' => $start_date
  , 'end_date' => $end_date
  ];
```

This is the output for array

```
Array ( 
  [24] => Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
       [item_id] => 10 
       [qty] => 1 
       [start_date] => 04-09-2016 
       [end_date] => 06-09-2016 
       ) 
     ) 
  [26] => Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 6
        [qty] => 1 
        [start_date] => 04-09-2016 
        [end_date] => 14-09-2016 
        ) 
      )
   )
```

[24][26] are renters' IDs

I wanted to delete one of the item from cart but this code I used before didn't work in this array. I've been searching through stackoverflow for hours but can't find the similar array.

This is the code for deleting a row from array

```
     foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $v){
           if($v['item_id'] == $removeditem) {
              unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }
         }
      }
```

Please advise me, I'd love to learn from you.
ps: my friend said this is not a multidimensional array, and I am actually weak in array. Please advise me, again :)

Comment: Do you session_start() at very beginning?

Comment: Do you get any errors, and what does happen?

Comment: yes, i did. I've included a file name session_check in every pages

Comment: I wasn't able to delete a particular record

Comment: great - so sessions are working. What is your proof it is not working - have you outputted the array after unset() and page refresh and seen it still there ?

Comment: I am looking for a way to delete a record but due to the structure of the array I created, the record can't be removed.

Comment: yes, after refreshing the page, it is still there

Comment: Are you sure it does not add the value to the session every page refresh, and then it deletes it, but adds a new one every time just before? There is no problem with your array (although rather messy). unset(array[][]) should work.

Comment: yes i am sure. Previously i did only one foreach loop and the array wasn't nested by renter's id , so the deletion code was working fine. Since I changed the array into this form, the code is not working anymore

Comment: try to run ` unset($_SESSION['cart'][24]);` and see if this way is working
and then, try to debug your foreach

Comment: all items belong to 24 are gone. Thanks for pointing this out. And finally I've figured out where the problem is. I really appreciate your help and time. Thanks a lot

Comment: PHP arrays are not multi-dimensional but are nested. The difference is subtle but significant.

Comment: hi @symcbean would you mind to explain it?

Comment: Post a new question asking for an explanation.